# What is the another way to add two excel sheets in one workbook using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I am facing issue with excel reports during creation of two excel sheets ine one workbook using vb.net, I was using Microsoft Excel 2007 for report generation it was good but unfortunately I need to uninstall all Microsoft Office Components and then I installed WPS office.Then this problem arise during generation of excel report.
here is the source code.

```
        Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
        Dim range, range1 As Excel.Range
        wb = a.Workbooks.Add
        Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet = wb.Worksheets(1)
        **Dim ws1 As Excel.Worksheet = wb.Worksheets(2)** -> On This Line
        ws1.Name = "MySheet2"
```

All was going good with Microsoft Office 2007 but its happening with WPS excel, In source code the section i marked as bold, when .net debug r goes there it directly goes to catch block and its gives this error **Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))**
Please Help me out
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new workbook like you have then you only get a Sheet1 so when you try to access a sheet with the index of 2 you get an invalid index because it does not exist.

Instead, you need to call the `Worksheets.Add` method.

Try this:

```
Dim ws1 As Excel.Worksheet = wb.Worksheets.Add()
ws1.Name = "MySheet2"
```